# How can I 'aws s3 sync' two buckets, which are located in different accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-iam

I'm trying to use 'aws s3 sync' on the awscli between two accounts.

Account A, I own. Account B, Owned by a third party.

Account B has given a user:jon on account A permission to a bucket through a role:assumeDevOps assumption.

Jon assumes assumeDevOps to access bucket on Account B. But now I have to sync to a bucket back on account A.

I'm getting an access denied. Possibly because that role that Jon assumed has no permissions to the bucket back on my account.

How do I do this?

Is there documentation on this specific situation?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you need to create a policy to allow access to the S3 bucket on your side and a role and attach this policy to the role.

Then, a user in Account B needs to assume this role you created which allows access to your bucket.

I believe that this is the article that you are looking for (the more elaborated one):
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html

And this is a more specific article:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/

Comment: But whoever assumes the role only has access to one of the buckets and not both. At least that is how its currently working.

Answer (score 1):

The credentials used to perform an `aws s3 sync` command require:

- Read permissions on the source bucket, *AND*
- Write permissions on the destination bucket

Since you are assuming a role from the source account (that already has read permissions on the source bucket), you will need to **grant permissions for that role to write to the destination bucket** in your account.

This can be done via a Bucket policy on the destination bucket, which would look something like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket"
            ],
            "Principal": {"AWS":"arn:aws:iam::bbbbbbbbbbbb:role/assumeDevOps"}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is the implication here that this should work without making _any_ changes to the source account? If so, that's not working for me. I see, "fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied" when trying to sync buckets between accounts when _only_ modifying permissions on the destination side.

Comment: @pdoherty926 I suggest that you create a new question rather than asking via a comment on an old question. Please include details of your particular setup.